# How do I unlock someone's iPhone 6 without providing the owner's Apple ID and password?

Tags: apple-id, password, iphone

How do I unlock someone's iPhone 6 without providing the owner's Apple ID and password?
I can not contact the owner to find out the Apple ID and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can *not* unlock the owner's iPhone 6 without providing the owner's Apple ID and password, or, if the owner created one, the passcode or password.  Apple does not keep that information, either.

The only thing you can do is to restore the owner's iPhone 6 from a previous backup, or set it up as a "new" iPhone.

Comment: How do I do that as it's still logged in to her Apple account